# Android studio "project and structure view" missing

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i don't have any idea what happened android studio settings but i have problem with all my project and new project i create.

I cant see "project", "structure" view on left pane. Actually it behaves there are no opened project on.

I take screen shoot, could you please give any advice to solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's your answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135268/project-view-is-not-showing-after-restarting-the-system-in-andriod-studio

Comment: Yes, it was about Fabric plugins , thanks you saved my day :)