# Project View is not showing after restarting the System in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After restarting my System i am not able to view the Project Structure of any of the project in Android Studio.

Previously i was able to choose Project view by going into View > Project but View menu is not showing such option now.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Are you using AS 1.3 beta ?

Comment: No it is Android Studio 1.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem happen to me this morning.

**Explanation :**
The Fabric/Crashalytics plugin failed somewhere which cause an IDE Error and the project will not be opened totaly.

**Solution :**
in `Android>Preferences>Plugins`, **disable** or uninstall **Fabric** for Android Studio, **restart** Android Studio. If the project view is not shown, reopen it.

Comment: Thanks i am trying, seems logical, i am using Fabric Plugin too.

Comment: Instead of uninstalling it, disabling it also helped to see the `Project` view.